# Creating composite columns cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

I need to store benchmark runs for each nightly builds. To do this, i came up with the following data model.

```
BenchmarkColumnFamily= {

   build_1: {
       (Run1, TPS) : 1000K
       (Run1, Latency) : 0.5ms
       (Run2, TPS) : 1000K
       (Run2, Latency) : 0.5ms
       (Run3, TPS) : 1000K
       (Run3, Latency) : 0.5ms
    }

    build_2: {
       ...
    }
...

}
```

To create such a schema, i came up with the following command on cassandra-cli:

```
create column family BenchmarkColumnFamily with 
    comparator = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)' AND 
    key_validation_class=UTF8Type AND
    default_validation_class=UTF8Type AND
    column_metadata = [
    {column_name: TPS, validation_class: UTF8Type}
    {column_name: Latency, validation_class: UTF8Type}
    ];
```

Does the above command create the schema i intend to create? The reason for my confusion is that, when i insert data into the above CF using:
 `set BenchmarkColumnFamily['1545']['TPS']='100';` 
it gets inserted successfully even though the comparator type is composite. Furthermore, even the following command gets executed successfully

```
set BenchmarkColumnFamily['1545']['Run1:TPS']='1000';
```

What is it that im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. The CLI is parsing the strings for values based on the type, probably using `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType<T>.fromString()`. And for Composite types, it uses ':' as field separator (not that I've seen documented, but I've experimented with Java code to convince myself.

Without a ':', it seems to just set the first part of the Composite, and leave the second as null. To set the second only, you can use

```
set BenchmarkColumnFamily['1545'][':NOT_TPS']='999';
```

From the CLI, dump out the CF:

```
list BenchmarkColumnFamily;
```

and you should see all the names (for all the rows), e.g.

```
RowKey: 1545
=> (column=:NOT_TPS, value=999, timestamp=1342474086048000)
=> (column=Run1:TPS, value=1000, timestamp=1342474066695000)
=> (column=TPS, value=100, timestamp=1342474057824000)
```

There is no way (via CLI) to constrain the composite elements to be non-null or specific values, that's something you'd have to do in code.

Also, the column_metadata option for the CF creation is unnecessary, since you've already listed the default validation as UTF8Type.

Answer (score 2):

The cassandra-cli tool is very limited in dealing with composites. Also, some unexpected things can happen in Cassandra with respect to validation of explicit, user-supplied composites. I don't know the exact answer for your situation, but I can tell you that you'll find this sort of model *vastly* easier to work with using the CQL 3 engine.

For example, your model could be expressed as:

```
CREATE TABLE BenchmarkColumnFamily (
    build text,
    run int,
    tps text,
    latency text,
    PRIMARY KEY (build, run)
);

INSERT INTO BenchmarkColumnFamily (build, run, tps, latency) VALUES ('1545', 1, '1000', '0.5ms');
```

See [this post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) for more information about how that translates to the storage-engine layer.

Comment: I don't think this matches the OP's schema; this will create a composite key. See the comments in [this post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) for details.

Comment: It creates a composite CQL key, not a composite Cassandra key. At the storage layer, this will create composite column names just like what he has. It really is not recommended to use Cassandra-cli for this sort of thing. (That post was written before cql3 was even a thing.)

Comment: ok, thanks.. will have to explore cql3 some more. Admittedly, I've been using CLI and/or Java api for most of my work.

Comment: See [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family#composite-columns) for how CQL maps multi-column primary keys to the storage layer.